# The first assumption leads to the third one that looks inconsistent at a glance. Can you explain it better?

Tags: inequality, derivatives, quadratics, curves

## Background

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> >
>   Given 2 distinct curves $C_1: y=f(x)=e^{6x}$ and $C_2: y=g(x)=ax^2$ where $a>0$. The objective is to find the range of $a$ such that there exists 2 tangents, each is tangent to both given curves.

I have solved it as follows.

1. Let $(t,e^{6t})$ be "a single point" on $C_1$ through which a tangent passes.

   The slope of the tangent is $6e^{6t}$ that is obtained from the first derivative of $f(x)=e^{6x}$ at $x=t$.

   The tangent is
   $$
   y-e^{6t} = 6e^{6t}(x-t)
   $$
2. Let $(u,au^2)$ be a point on $C_2$ through which the tangent passes. It means that the tangent and $C_2$ have only one intersection point  $(u,au^2)$.

   We have,
   $$
    au^2 -e^{6t} = 6e^{6t}(u-t)
    $$
   By arranging it, we have a quadratic equation in $u$.
   $$
    au^2 -6e^{6t}u + e^{6t}(6t-1) =0
    $$

   In order to make the quadratic equation have twin roots, its discriminant must be equal to zero as follows.
   $$
   (-6e^{6t})^2-4\times a\times e^{6t}(6t-1) =0
   $$
3. There will be 2 tangents if there are 2 roots $t_1$  and $t_2$ for the equation in $t$ below.
   $$
   (-6e^{6t})^2-4\times a\times e^{6t}(6t-1) =0
   $$

   We can interpret finding the roots of the equation as finding the abscissa $t$ of the intersection of $\alpha(t)=a$ and $\beta(t)=\frac{9e^{6t}}{6t-1}$.

   Using derivative, we can determine the minimum value of $\beta$ which is $9e^2$. Thus $a>9e^2$ is the required range.

## My confusion

In the first step I must assume there is a single $t$ but in the last step I have to assume there are 2 roots $t_1$ and $t_2$. It looks inconsisten, doesn't it? What is wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Nobody gets interested to answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

I will repeat your solution with some justifications.

The tangent line to $y = e^{6 x}$ at the point $(\xi, e^{6\xi})$ is 
\begin{equation*} 
y = 6 e^{6\xi}(x-\xi) + e^{6\xi}. 
\end{equation*}
A line in the above family is tangent to the graph $y = a x^2$ if and only if the equation
\begin{equation*} 
a x^2 = 6 e^{6\xi}(x-\xi) + e^{6\xi} 
\end{equation*}
has a unique solution for $x$. The last equation has a unique solution for $x$ if and only if
\begin{equation*} 
9 e^{6\xi} -6 a \xi +a = 0, 
\end{equation*}
that is, if and only if
\begin{equation*} 
a = \frac{9 e^{6\xi}}{6 \xi -1} 
\end{equation*}
Since $a \gt 0$, we conclude that the tangent line 
\begin{equation*} 
y = 6 e^{6\xi}(x-\xi) + e^{6\xi}. 
\end{equation*}
is a tangent line to $y = a x^2$ if and only if
\begin{equation*} 
a = \frac{9 e^{6\xi}}{6 \xi -1} \quad \text{and} \quad \xi \gt \frac{1}{6}. 
\end{equation*}
There will be two tangent lines to $y = e^{6x}$ that are tangent to $y=ax^2$ if and only if the equation 
\begin{equation*} 
a = \frac{9 e^{6\xi}}{6 \xi -1} 
\end{equation*}
has two solutions for $\xi$ such that $\xi > 1/6$. Finally, as you pointed out, this is the case if and only if $a \gt 9e^2$.